# How can I quickly filter a hash given an array of keys?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, filter

This is an over-engineered solution for something I think can be done better. Basically it takes an array of keys to create a filter string, which is checked against every key in the hash to see if that key has an index in the filter string... The exclude flag flips the logic to include or exclude based on the result of _filter. Probably not the best way.  Any better ways?

```
  sub _filter{
    my ($filter,$key,$joiner) = @_;
    $joiner = $joiner ? $joiner : '+';
    my $i = index($filter,$key);
    if($i >= 0){  
      my $c;
      $c = substr($filter, $i-1, 1); 

      print STDERR "\nc => $c [$key][$i]";

      if($i==0){ return 1; }
      return($c eq $joiner);  
    }
    return 0;
  }

  sub hashFilter{
    my($hash,$filter_keys,$exclude) = @_;
    return 0 unless isHash($hash) && $filter_keys;

    $exclude = $exclude ? $exclude : 0;
    my $filter = isArray($filter_keys)? join('+',@$filter_keys) : $filter_keys;
    print STDERR "FILTER is > $filter";

    my $p = {map { ( _filter($filter,$_) == $exclude )  ? ($_ => $$hash{$_}) : () } keys %$hash};

    return $p;
  }

#isArray() and isHash() just check the ref value for "ARRAY" or "HASH" respectively
```

...using standard perl without additional Modules! =]

Some thoughts here?

Using map, and index... are these fast-ish methods vs doing regex, or are there better functions to use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hash slice, anyone? :

```
my %filtered_hash;
@filtered_keys = grep { exists $hash{$_} } @filtered_keys;
@filtered_hash{@filtered_keys} = @hash{@filtered_keys};
```

Comment: This will add `undef`s to the filtered hash for keys that don't exist in the original hash, but you can fix that by preprocessing the key list with `@filtered_keys = grep exists $hash{$_}, @filtered_keys;`.

Answer (score 16):

```
my %filtered_hash = map { $_ => $hash{$_} } grep { exists $hash{$_} } @filter_keys;
```

Comment: or pack map and grep together `map {exists $hash{$_} ? ($_ => $hash{$_}) : ()} @filter_keys`

Comment: @EricStrom This was exactly what I wanted! Short and sweet.